# I want to embed a radio player with simple interface to play different radio channels , How can i do this?

Tags: flash, adobe, embed, internet-radio

I dont have enough info about making a swf and use flasvars attribute.Briefly i want you to help me or give an idea how can i make a simple radio player with simple interface like play , pause , volume buttons and embed to somewhere in my web page. This radio player will include different radio channels.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/dynstream_actionscript.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to learn whatever coding languages that are required for this. You could code a javascript one or a flash one. It's all up to you. This isn't really a question either.. your asking us to make one for you.

Comment: i know i have to code a flash , is there any application that i can make .swf objects ? I have also javascript knowledge , but how can i code a radio player with simple interface with js ?